# unable to configure spring cloud stream Kafka Binder to connect to broker

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using stream bridge for sending kafka messages

`streamBridge.send("alm-foo-dev", "kafka", message)`

My tests however fail connecting to the Kafka broker

```
2022-07-12 12:29:41.095  WARN 79618 --- [read | consumer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-1, groupId=consumer] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:41.158  WARN 79618 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:41.205  WARN 79618 --- [read | consumer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-1, groupId=consumer] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:41.262  WARN 79618 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:41.378  WARN 79618 --- [read | consumer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-1, groupId=consumer] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:41.519  WARN 79618 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:41.769  WARN 79618 --- [read | consumer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-1, groupId=consumer] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:41.884  WARN 79618 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:42.679  WARN 79618 --- [read | consumer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-1, groupId=consumer] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:42.688  WARN 79618 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:43.693  WARN 79618 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:43.839  WARN 79618 --- [read | consumer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-1, groupId=consumer] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:44.865  WARN 79618 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-07-12 12:29:44.983  WARN 79618 --- [read | consumer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-1, groupId=consumer] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9952) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No records found for topic

    at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(KafkaTestUtils.java:181)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(KafkaTestUtils.java:142)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.WebhooksFunctionTests.testPublishesHttpMessageToKafka(WebhooksFunctionTests.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Here's how I configure embedded Kafka

```
@EmbeddedKafka(
        brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9952", "port=9952"},
        topics = {"alm-jira-dev"},
        partitions = 1
)
```

and the `src/test/java/application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 29191
logging:
  level:
    root: ERROR
    org:
      springframework.integration: DEBUG
      springframework.cloud.stream: DEBUG
      springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo: WARN
    com.digite.cloud: DEBUG
spring:
  application:
    name: howler
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  mongodb:
    embedded:
      version: 3.4.6
  data:
    mongodb:
      port: 29129
      host: localhost
      database: howler_db
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        default:
          producer:
            useTopicHeader: true
        binder:
          defaultBrokerPort: 9952
          autoCreateTopics: false
          producerProperties:
            key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value.serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
            max.block.ms: 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration worked for me (running tests)

```
spring:
  embedded:
    kafka:
      brokers: localhost:9092
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        default:
          producer:
            useTopicHeader: true
        binder:
          autoCreateTopics: false
          producerProperties:
            key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value.serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
            max.block.ms: 100
```

Yet to figure out what will the config look like when I deploy the app to Kube.